# how to pass values as an argument in java?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, arguments

i don't know if the title is right. I'm doing a project for a petrol station in java. There is a question that reads as:

write method:
*addFuel() which passes in an amount of petrol to be added to the pump as an argument and updates the **appropriate variables as necessary**. No return data required.*

i have a instance variable for the amount of petrol in the pump.

i'm still somewhat new to java and don't fully understand how to answer this question. i cant seem get java to click to me. This is probably a easy question but i need help.

Comment: the argument is in this case the amount of fuel...

Comment: addFuel(double amount)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the method's signature is the [parameters it receives](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html). In your case, you need to pass an amount (for argument's sake, let's say it's a `double`) and add it to your data member:

```
public void addFuel(double amountToAdd) {
    amount += amountToAdd;
}
```

Comment: should beginner's always use `this.` for instance variables? Just a style question.

Comment: @JamesKPolk It's more of  a stylistic question than anything else. Personally, I'd only use `this` in constructors and setters.

Comment: @JamesKPolk the more interesting point is: when dealing with physical units add the actual unit to the variable and or method name like `addFuelInGalons(double ammountInGalons)`. That would have saved [Mars Climate Orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter)...